# How to stop a process gracefully before killing its buffer?

Tags: shell, ess, process

I want to make a function that stops the [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) inferior process (e.g. an R or Julia shell), kills its buffer and deletes its window. `ess-inf.el` provides the function [`ess-quit`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/7ec23bf341c23445c98f5e1faf6a1369b92f2e9f/lisp/ess-inf.el#L2328) to exit the inferior process, so my first attempt was

```lisp
(defun kill-ess-inf-buffer-and-window ()
  "Exit the inferior ESS process, kill its buffer and delete its
window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ess-process-buffer (ess-get-process-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer ess-process-buffer ; Otherwise ESS inserts the command for quitting in the source code buffer, if this function is invoked from there.
      (ess-quit)
      (delete-window (get-buffer-window ess-process-buffer))
      (kill-buffer ess-process-buffer))))
```

but Emacs asks me about killing the buffer because it has a running process. Apparently `kill-buffer` runs before `ess-quit` has finished its job, so I tried adding a `(sleep-for 0.1)` before `(kill-buffer ess-process-buffer)` and Emacs didn't ask anymore, but I guess there is a more robust way of doing it.

`gnuplot.el` has a function that does for gnuplot shells exactly what I'm trying to do for ESS shells, [`gnuplot-kill-gnuplot-buffer`](https://github.com/emacs-gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/9a31a12903cd3d9eb413948ef206023917c0d469/gnuplot.el#L1435):

```lisp
(defun gnuplot-kill-gnuplot-buffer ()
  "Kill the gnuplot process and its display buffers."
  (interactive)
  (if (and gnuplot-process
           (eq (process-status gnuplot-process) 'run))  ;; <SE>
      (kill-process gnuplot-process))
  (if (and gnuplot-buffer (get-buffer gnuplot-buffer))
      (progn
        (if (one-window-p) ()
          (delete-window (get-buffer-window gnuplot-buffer)))
        (kill-buffer gnuplot-buffer)))
  (setq gnuplot-process nil
        gnuplot-buffer nil))
```

It uses `kill-process`, but I don't know how that function works. Is it a request for a graceful shutdown or a `SIGDIEMOTHERF**ER`? I don't want to brutally murder my inferior ESS processes.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339604/automatically-stopping-a-process-when-exiting-emacs

Comment: You could use a process sentinel to kill the associated buffer as soon as the process reports that it has exited.  Or you could simply assume that the process *will* exit and wait for that to happen, something like `(when-let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))) (while (buffer-live-p proc) (sit-for 0.1)))`

Comment: Hi @phils :-) > _You could use a process sentinel to kill the associated buffer as soon as the process reports that it has exited._ I was thinking about that so I read about process sentinels in the manual, but I can't figure out how to do it. Can you tell me, please?

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp)Signals to Processes` regarding `kill-process` and friends.

Comment: I'll leave you to research that; no time to follow up right now.  It's more complex than the other option.

Comment: @phils What do you think of my answer? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a template for a function that kills the process and buffer of a shell `SHELL` and deletes its window.

```lisp
(defun kill-SHELL-inf-buffer-and-window ()
  "Exit the inferior <SHELL> process, kill its buffer and delete its
window."
  (interactive)
  (set-process-sentinel
   (get-process SHELL-PROCESS-NAME)
   (lambda (process event)
     (ORIGNAL-SENTINEL-FUNCTION-IF-ANY process event)
     (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
          (buffer-live-p (process-buffer process))
          (kill-buffer (process-buffer process)))))
  (delete-window (get-buffer-window (process-buffer (get-process SHELL-PROCESS-NAME))))
  (FUNCTION-THAT-QUITS-SHELL))
```

The function below applies it to shells launched by ESS.

---

As suggested by phils in the comments, here I use a process sentinel to kill the buffer as soon as the process reports it has exited. Or at least that's the idea. From the first tests it seems like it works.

**Edit** updated according to phils' suggestions.

```lisp
(defun kill-ess-inf-buffer-and-window ()
  "Exit the inferior ESS process, kill its buffer and delete its
window."
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (ess-get-process-buffer)
    (set-process-sentinel
     (ess-get-process ess-local-process-name)
     (lambda (process event)
       (ess-process-sentinel process event) ; Run ESS’s own sentinel.
       (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
            (buffer-live-p (process-buffer process))
            (kill-buffer (process-buffer process)))))
    (ess-quit)
    (delete-window (get-buffer-window (ess-get-process-buffer)))))
```

Notes:

- [`ess-get-process`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/86d1bce8b53522a5939924960025799e66d9414e/lisp/ess-inf.el#L683) is ESS's counterpart of `get-process`. It takes a process name as argument and returns the corresponding process object.
- [`ess-get-process-buffer`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/86d1bce8b53522a5939924960025799e66d9414e/lisp/ess-inf.el#L975) is ESS's counterpart of `process-buffer`. It retrieves the the buffer associated with the process.
- [`ess-local-process-name`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/86d1bce8b53522a5939924960025799e66d9414e/lisp/ess-custom.el#L1492) is where the name of the process is stored.
- I use `(with-current-buffer (ess-get-process-buffer) …)` because otherwise ESS inserts the command for quitting in the source code buffer, if the function is invoked from there.
- `(delete-window)` alone causes the screen to flicker when the window is deleted, while `(delete-window (get-buffer-window (ess-get-process-buffer)))` prevents the flickering but it works only if called after `ess-quit`. I don't know why, I think it’s due to something that `ess-quit` does.

Comment: Nice one.  A couple of things... 1. You should set the sentinel *before* calling `ess-quit` -- it may well never make a difference in practice, but in *principle* if the process died instantly your sentinel might never have a chance to run if you don't try to set it until *after* you've asked it to exit.  And 2, always check the signal in a sentinel: `(lambda (process signal) (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal)) (buffer-live-p (process-buffer process)) (kill-buffer (process-buffer process))))`

Comment: n.b. I would usually be dealing with `(process-buffer process)` within a sentinel function, so I've shown that, but I don't know what `(ess-get-process-buffer)` actually does.

Comment: @phils Thanks for the tips :-) Why not use `process-live-p`? The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html#index-process_002dlive_002dp) says _A process is considered alive if its status is `run`, `open`, `listen`, `connect` or `stop`._ So I thought I _was_ checking the signal.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason why you call `kill-buffer` within the `and` form?

Comment: That's fair enough -- your `process-live-p` approach was probably fine.  I'd be inclined to use explicit status tests as a general rule in sentinels, though -- sentinels can be called for a number of reasons, so I think it makes the purpose clearer.  Regarding the `and` form, that's just personal preference -- `(and x y z)` is simpler than `(when (and x y) z)`.  The byte compiler will optimise the latter to the former, though, so it makes no real difference.

Comment: My other tip about sentinels is to remember that a process has only one of them -- if you set a sentinel, you're replacing any pre-existing sentinel.  As such, it can be a good idea to figure out if it's just using `internal-default-process-sentinel` (the default), or if there's something else already configured.  If necessary you could call he original function explicitly in your sentinel, or else use something along the lines of `(add-function :after (process-sentinel proc) #'my-sentinel)` (which I haven't tested, but `(elisp)Advising Functions` provides a similar example for filters).

Comment: @phils ESS does set [its own sentinel](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-inf.el#L560) for its processes, but if I advise it I guess it'll kill the process' buffer and window every time I exit one, which is not what I want. Is there something wrong with replacing a sentinel like my function does?

Comment: Case-by-case -- it 100% depends on what the original sentinel does.  In that example I see there's *another* buffer (`:accum_buffer` ?) which the default sentinel kills at the beginning, so maybe you *do* want that to run first, to ensure it cleans up after itself?  You can call `ess-process-sentinel` in your function as an alternative to advice, which is quite likely to be equivalent in practice (i.e. so long as nothing else is messing with the sentinel for this).